# Add index to jar file, referencing external jar file

Tags: java, jar

I am trying a simple [index creation](https://github.com/malaterre/vtk-dicom/commit/4ff52c33ed88b8bdd6c142ccaf8ac0578cfd84d5) on a jar file. However it fails with:

```
$ jar -i /tmp/vtk-dicom/bin/lib/vtkdicom.jar
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/vtk-dicom/bin/lib/vtk.jar (No such file or directory)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:215)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:145)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:154)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:91)
    at sun.tools.jar.Main.getJarPath(Main.java:1052)
    at sun.tools.jar.Main.getJarPath(Main.java:1068)
    at sun.tools.jar.Main.genIndex(Main.java:1084)
    at sun.tools.jar.Main.run(Main.java:269)
    at sun.tools.jar.Main.main(Main.java:1177)
```

On obvious work-around is simply:

```
$ cp /usr/share/java/vtk.jar /tmp/vtk-dicom/bin/lib/
```

However it is ugly and error-prone. Is there any other way I can tell `jar -i` where to search for a different `vtk.jar` location ? I will need a portable solution which works on Windows/Linux/MacOSX.

For information the manifest is set to:

```
$ cat ./Source/java/manifest.txt
Class-Path: vtk.jar
```

For information, if I change it to:

```
$ cat ./Source/java/manifest.txt
Class-Path: /usr/share/java/vtk.jar
```

It gives a slightly different error:

```
$ jar -i /tmp/vtk-dicom/bin/lib/vtkdicom.jar
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/vtk-dicom/bin/lib/usr/share/java/vtk.jar (No such file or directory)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:215)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:145)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:154)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:91)
    at sun.tools.jar.Main.getJarPath(Main.java:1052)
    at sun.tools.jar.Main.getJarPath(Main.java:1068)
    at sun.tools.jar.Main.genIndex(Main.java:1084)
    at sun.tools.jar.Main.run(Main.java:269)
    at sun.tools.jar.Main.main(Main.java:1177)
```

For reference:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_75"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.4) (7u75-2.5.4-2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.75-b04, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Please, put the content of your MANIFEST file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found any documentation on this, but it seems to work if you provide the other jars after the main jar:

```
jar -i main.jar other.jar
```

For your example:

```
cd /tmp/vtk-dicom/bin/lib/
jar -i vtkdicom.jar /usr/share/java/vtk.jar
```

The other jar files are not modified.  No changes are needed for the manifest.

Edit:

The generated INDEX.LIST file contains the full path that you specify for "main.jar", so I've modified my example to "cd" into the directory first.  Otherwise, the jar file might not work after it is installed in its final location.

Alternatively, "jar -i" can be run on the file after it is installed.

Answer (score -1):

First you need to specify within your MANIFEST file the Class-Path for that JAR.
The option *i* it's only for creating an INDEX.LIST file that will optimize the loading of classes.

So you need to put in your MANIFEST the whole path to the JAR.